# how do you modify executable jar classes in eclipse?

Tags: java, executable-jar, twitter4j

Im attempting to follow a tutorial here that will help me to modify some source code from the twitter4j executable jar to allow me to use twitters native image upload api, unfortunately Im having a tough time figuring out how this is done because these files arent allowing me to edit them at all in eclipse, [here is the tutorial im following](http://sholtz9421.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/using-update_with_media-with-twitter4j/#comment-17) seems pretty straight forward but the author didnt include the step of how to edit the files assuming this was common knowledge I can only assume.

Comment: A jar file is essentially a glorified zip file with some extras attached so it can be run automatically by java. You can safely convert the file to a zip file by simply replacing .jar in the file name with .zip

Answer (score 2):

You have two options open to you.

1) Get the original source code, and package the jar after making your changes.

2) Unzip the jar (any standard unzipping program should do), make your changes and then repackage the jar.

That said, perusing those links (I didn't go very in depth) suggests that those are libraries you can use - not libraries you are required to modify to get to work. What are you trying to achieve by modifying the library?

Comment: Im attempting to upload images directly to twitter using their api, unfortunately twitter4j has not implemented this into their library, this author seems to of figured out a way of doing this so I wanted to give this a try and see if it actually works

Comment: The blog seems to suggest that you modify their implementation of the class "TwitterImpl". All you need to do is copy this class, name it "MyTwitterImpl" (or something else) and make your changes. You can use the same references that library uses, have your changes independent of the library (no ungainly repacking) and get the same functionality. This is the glory of OOP. Just remember to give credit in the comments to the original authors.

Comment: what about the first step where the author said "1. Find the “StatusMethods” class in the “twitter4j.api” package, and add the following interface”:" is this not needed, will it work with just step 2?

Comment: This is a badly written blog post. After git-cloning the repo, I find that StatusMethods is an interface, and what he probably means is 'implement the StatusMethods interface with a class that includes the following method'. He then provides the implementation for that method.

Comment: well this is no good, I think I will give up on image upload to twitter/twitpic/yfrog etc using twitter4j, the documentation for this is tough to figure out and quite stressful lol

Comment: The documentation is horrid, but no worse than you will generally find - so it's not a terrible exercise. In any event, you should be sure to accept answers, so people are more likely to respond to requests for help in the future. ;-)